# How to get latest record in GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, laravel

I write this query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `peer_settings` 
WHERE `sorting_hub_id` LIKE '[\"172\"]' 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY `peer_settings`.`product_id` ASC
```

when I run this query I got Id 488 product
id 100

but I want id 46595 product id 100

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL, you can [order by](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) more than one column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `peer_settings` 
WHERE `sorting_hub_id` LIKE '[\"172\"]' 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY `peer_settings`.`product_id` ASC,`peer_settings`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: got the same result, this is not working for me

Comment: you want only one record?

Comment: yes, i want the latest entry regarding for sorting_hub_id and product_id (combination)

Comment: you can use "limit" , like the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the having clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM `peer_settings` 
WHERE `sorting_hub_id` LIKE '[\"172\"]' 
GROUP BY product_id  having max(id)
ORDER BY `peer_settings`.`product_id` ASC
```

Comment: got the same result, this is not working for me

Comment: Are you not getting result with  id 46595 product id 100 in given answer?

Comment: if you need only one result than you can use limit clause at the end of the query   LIMIT 1